# Does Kubeadm reset delete persistent volumes

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I need to change the advertise address of my Kubernetes master node.

I can do this with a kubeadm reset, but I don't want to lose my (rook-ceph) persistent volumes on the master node.

Is it safe to do a kubeadm reset or do I need to backup my PVs first?

Is there another safe way to change the advertise address?

Answer (score 1):

To not lose the data you need to backup  PV and then execute `kubeadm reset` command.

`kubeadm reset`  is responsible for cleaning up a node local file system from files that were created using the  `kubeadm init`  or  `kubeadm join`  commands. For control-plane nodes  `reset`  also removes the local stacked etcd member of this node from the etcd cluster and also removes this node's information from the kubeadm  `ClusterStatus`  object.  `ClusterStatus`  is a kubeadm managed Kubernetes API object that holds a list of kube-apiserver endpoints.

`kubeadm reset phase`  can be used to execute the separate phases of the above workflow. To skip a list of phases you can use the  `--skip-phases`  flag, which works in a similar way to the  `kubeadm join`  and  `kubeadm init`  phase runners.

The "reset" command executes the following phases:

```
preflight              Run reset pre-flight checks
update-cluster-status  Remove this node from the ClusterStatus object.
remove-etcd-member     Remove a local etcd member.
cleanup-node           Run cleanup node.
```

Take a look: [kubeadm-reset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/#reset-workflow).

While normal usage of cluster to not lose the PV make sure that it has **Retain** [Reclaim Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/). Otherwise execute `kubectl patch pv <your-pv-name> -p "{\"spec\":{\"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy\":\"Retain\"}}"`.  PVs then will not be automatically deleted when a user deletes claim.